# Magento - adding button to media storage

Tags: php, magento, button

I am struggling with a simple task - add one new button to Magento Media Storage, e.g. under the buttons called "Browse files" and "Upload files".

I have override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Wysiwyg_Images_Content_Uploader` with a function

```
protected function _prepareLayout(){
       $this->setChild('test_button',
                $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('test_button'),
                        'onclick'   => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.upload()',
                        'type'    => 'button',
                        'class' => 'go'
                ))
        );
       return $this;
}
```

Now I am trying to edit `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\cms\browser\content.phtml` by adding this line

```
<div id="contents-uploader"><?php echo  $this->getChildHtml('uploadURL') ?> </div>
```

However, my button does not show up. The modul extends Uploader correctly as when I write 
`echo "something";` 
it appears in the pop-up window of the Storage.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: `root/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf`

Comment: Could you please explain me what I should do with that?

Comment: you can't do anything with it. But you can add your own buttons to `adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml` and make own controller for actions

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, isn't it?

Comment: If you need to add new button in backend under `browse/upload` edit `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml` and place your code under 36 row http://i.stack.imgur.com/m40r4.png